# Strange hover behavior based on order of sibling markup

Tags: css, css-transitions, markup

I found a strange issue while hovering over a div that took me some time to troubleshoot. I'm curious to why this happened to help myself and others in the future.

```
<div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" alt="" />
  <h3>Smoooth</h3>
</div>
<div>
  <h3>Janky</h3>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" alt="" />
</div>
```

Essentially, hover over the first one i get the expected result. But when the h3 is before the image, it acts all janky.

codepen attached.

See the Pen [zqZOPN](http://codepen.io/szyam/pen/zqZOPN/) by Mark Szymanski

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the bug is that the `h3` is visible in the second version. It should be hidden behind the `img` since it comes before it in the `DOM`.
For some weird reason, if you change the `opacity` of the `img` to a value less that 1, the `h3` disappears, as it should.

```
img {
  display: block;
  opacity: .99;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity 200ms ease-in-out;
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
section {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 3em auto;
}
div {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 48%;
  margin: 1%;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}
img {
  display: block;
  opacity: .99;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity 200ms ease-in-out;
}
h3 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  top: 50%;
  left: 15%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 70%;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding: 1em;
  transform: translateY(-75%);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: background-color 200ms ease-in-out;
}
div:hover h3 {
  background-color: transparent;
}
div:hover img {
  opacity: 0.25;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h4>Why does the h3 jump on hover when it's placed before the image in the mark-up?</h4>
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" alt="" />
    <h3>Smoooth</h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>Janky</h3>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" alt="" />
  </div>
</section>
```

And that is the reason of the flickering, because as soon as the `img` `opacity` changes to a value lower than 1, the `h3` hides behind the `img`.

To solve your problem, you have to add `z-index:1` to your `h3` to force it to come in frond of the `img`

Comment: Thanks @xpy for the breakdown. Think i get it. That 0.99 trick is crazy, would've never tried that lol.